# Invoke-RestMethod {Message: "The request is invalid."}

Tags: rest, api, powershell

The following curl command successfully makes the API call and returns the expected output:

```
curl -X GET "https://<rootURI>/calc/add?a={14}&b={22}" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <key value>" --insecure
```

When I try using Invoke-RestMethod however I receive the following response:

```
ERROR: Invoke-RestMethod : {"Message":"The request is invalid."}
```

My PowerShell code snippet is:

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$header = @{ 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' = '<key value>' }
$uri = 'https://<rootURI>/calc/add?a={14}&b={22}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $header
```

I also tried to force the use of TLS 1.2 with the following line and got the same result.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As curl is working, try to use Invoke-WebRequest. Now it's aliased curl in powershell V5: Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=$keyvalue} -Uri "https://<rootURI>/calc/add?a={14}&b={22}" -Method GET

Comment: I actually have curl.exe installed and am removing the alias via my PS profile with this line: `remove-item alias:curl`
I tried swapping Invoke-RestMethod for Invoke-WebRequest, but I am still getting the same response. Further testing revealed the [System.Net.WebException] error is `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

Comment: Pass -vL to curl command to know what is the header sent by curl and follow redirects and how curl handle --insecure. Modify the headers of powershell to match header of curl.

Comment: Thank you @M.Hassan! I followed your instructions, and found that curl was stripping the curly braces from my parameter values.  I removed them from the URL in my PoSh code and got it working

Comment: Welcome. I'm Glad  that you resolved your issue.